# Setting up Diffuse, Illumination, Bump and Specular mapping

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I'm stuck importing this .3DS model and thought of asking for some help.

If there is a model A imported, but textures must be mapped manually. On the object C of model A, there is material C, and all the textures related to C are named C-blah blah blah.

But here is the thing, there are C-Diffuse, C-Illumination, C-Specular.
How do I apply all of them onto the object C?

I wish I could've explain it in detail, but my PC isn't feeling that good...

Thanks in advance.

+Edit:
[image: The model and texture]
This is the model I am working with. It comes with multiple textures for a single part. How do I have it all go into one things?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you are going to need to take a few steps back and understand how textures work before you can get that working without lots of step by step instructions. There is a pretty good tutorial here that should help: [Blender Guru Principled Shader](https://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/2017/6/21/how-to-use-blenders-new-ultimate-shader-principled-bsdf)

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign them manually as *image texture* in *shader material node editor*.

Well, unfortunately the maps you mention are just the general output for some standard **behavior** that we describe those properties in shader. Most of the 3D modeling application follow the same rule to make it work, but still a little bit difference in code details. So Blender will not (and shouldn't) directly support other material created in other software. So not much automatic create material method in Blender. (Yet there is a Principled BSDF which developed by Disney for general use)

But there is some addon that handle these material well, you should find those addon first. And Blender 2.80 is trying to do a more  intelligent material structure, it might come with some better solution at that time.